# Make floating div fill container?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Trying to get a floating div to fill the height of its parent, but the `#sidebar` doesn't seem to want to expand past `auto`.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FDQKm/

Any suggestions?

Comment: What dialect of CSS are you using in your example?

Comment: Can you please add a little more to your description and explain exactly what it is that you're trying to do?

Comment: @MrLister: [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: @j08691 Pretty straightforward problem. Outer div has a min-height of 400px, inner div has 100%, so calculated height of outer div comes out as 400px, while inner div calculates to 72px. How come?

Comment: @MrLister Yep, that's the problem I'm having.

Comment: I think the problem is that the first element up without `height: 100%` only has `min-height` set, and everything below that is just inheriting the auto. If you change the height of `#main` to a fixed value ( http://jsfiddle.net/nSAja/ ), it fills it correctly (but overflows, and then `#main` won't expand properly.)

Answer (score 2):

Height:100% has never worked for me.  What I've always done is made divs *appear* to be full height by applying "overflow:hidden" to the parent div (main in your case), and then adding a "padding-bottom:5000px;margin-bottom:-5000px;" to the div I'm trying to make look full height.  This will extend any backgrounds and side borders that happen to be there, as if the element was actually the full height of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

make the parent div position= relative and then resize your inner div.
height of the inner div should be :  height:100%